# How does Xtra-PC work?

Tags: usb

I came across this device [here](http://www.studylifestyle.com/2016/xtra-pc/1/?cid=12&utm_term=gawkermedia-lifehacker&sxid=ajaoiq11daui). Can anybody explain how does [Xtra-PC](https://www.xtra-pc.com/) work?

Comment: I can smell snake-oil...

Comment: I'd guess it is essentially just a USB flash stick with Linux on it masquerading as a "New PC".  Many flavours of Linux can boot from a flash stick and "feel" faster than a corrupted or virus laden (or even virus-scanner laden) copy of Windows.  As mentioned by Tetsujin, snake-oil basically.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [their site](https://www.xtra-pc.com/how-it-works-1/):

> Xtra-PC Runs Through Your USB Port
>
> **Xtra-PC is a flash drive stick** that you insert into an available USB
>   port on your PC. **Built on the proven foundation of Linux, it bypasses
>   the old, slow, bloated Windows operating system** to make your PC into a
>   blazing fast, high performance PC with a new, simple to use, operating
>   system that has the familiar look and feel of your Windows PC.  It
>   even works with missing or faulty hard drives. Since it runs on a USB
>   stick, your existing computer is not altered, and youʼll have access
>   to all of your old files. You simply plug it in, restart your PC to
>   boot into USB, and start using Xtra-PC!
>
> Xtra-PC is easy to use and made for speed.

It does nothing special, is **not** "a new PC", and anyone can achieve a similar effect by downloading and using a Linux Live USB/CD/DVD image.

Comment: I think that must be mentioned that a similar effect can be achieved **ONLY** by using a lightweight Linux distribution - http://goo.gl/zsE0a3. The Xtra-PC is based on Lubuntu (at least it was in 2015) - http://goo.gl/5tE4g0.